# My code should connect to http stream and rstp stream, but It isn't. any ideas?

Tags: java, android, rtsp, rtp

So I am wondering why I can connect to this radio stream (http://51.255.127.128:8016/stream) but I cannot seem to connect to a VLC rtsp or rtp stream. I was under the impression that I could simply connect to rtp://hostaddress:port# but it seems that I can't get a connection. Is there any way I can avoid using the rtp classes and just do it directly using the method shown below?

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.io.IOException;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   Button button_stop;
   Button button_play;
   Uri stream_data= Uri.parse("http://51.255.127.128:8016/stream"); 
   //works for rtsp and http
   //private String STREAM_URL ="http://51.255.127.128:8016/stream";
   private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       button_stop=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Stop_b);
       button_play=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Play_b);

       mPlayer=new MediaPlayer();

       button_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v){

               try{

                   mPlayer.reset();
                   mPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.this,stream_data);
                   mPlayer.prepare();
                   mPlayer.start();
                ;

              } catch (IOException e){
                  e.printStackTrace();

              }

           }

       });

     button_stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v){

               mPlayer.stop();

           }

       });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use prepareAsync.

```
    mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
    mPlayer.prepareAsync();
```